# How can fix the syntax of a cut-off JSON string by adding characters?

Tags: php, json

I am having JSON strings that sometimes get cut off in my database. Unsurprisingly, they cannot be parsed by the PHP function `json_decode()`. Instead of returning `null`, I want the function to return the value that are still readable. For this, I need to add `"]}` chars and possibly even `:` in order to produce valid JSON again.

E.g.

`{"a":"b","c":"d`

should become

`{"a":"b","c":"d"}`

This sounds complex. Are there any solution to this except writing a full-blown JSON parser?
Are there libraries or functions for that?

Comment: Short answer: no. I would rather aim on the source of the problem. Why does it strips sometimes in your database? My tip is that you are using column type `varchar` limited with `255` characters. You can use type `text` instead of it.

Comment: Why would you store a cut off json string?

Comment: Fix the data corruption, and then everything else is not an issue.

Comment: No I am using the `text` type. And even when I'll find the cause, there are already many cut-off strings in the DB that should be fixed anyway :-(

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have any built-in functions to do this.

I've searched for "PHP fix broken JSON automatically" and found an opensource library which tries to accomplish this task.
Please take a look: https://github.com/adhocore/php-json-fixer